# Disabling Vista-Style controls in Application

Tags: c++, windows-vista, controls, styles

So I'm trying to recompile an application to add some minor features.  All is well, except for one thing.

The old version has all the windows-vista-style dialog buttons.  The corners are rounded, the radio buttons look different, etc.

[Example](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?b4af48c189.png)

How do I turn those things on?  I want it to look/feel like the original.

EDIT:  If anyone knows how to make that picture imbed inline, go for it...  I couldn't get it.

Comment: What compiler and what version of Windows SDK are you using?

Comment: Your version is the classic style, not Vista. The Vista appearance seems to be on 'Their Version'. Presumably you want your version to also appear with the Vista styles?

Comment: @Danny:  Yes, that's what I meant.  It seems to be backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your version has classic window style (not Vista). To use Vista style as in "THEIR VERSION" check that somewhere in headers there is the following code:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#if defined _M_IX86
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_IA64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='ia64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
#endif
```

If that code is there(and I think it should be there) you should check that you have compiled UNICODE version( with _UNICODE defined).

More details about enabling Vista Common Controls you could read in [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531404.aspx).